# Unevenly spaced levels with tricontourf and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, colorbar, contourf

I am trying to interpolate & plot some irregularly spaced data as a contour plot. I want to manually set the contour levels to some arbitrary values. The problem I am running into is the colorbar. I want each level to have its own color, but when I manually pass an arraylike of my desired contour levels to `tricontourf`, the colorbar sets all but one level to the same color, and the final level to the next color in sequence.

[The data used to generate the plot](https://pastebin.com/x3gUm1VM)

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('testdata.txt')

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.max(z)]

plt.figure()

cntr1 = plt.tricontourf(x,y,z, levels=levels, cmap="viridis_r")
plt.colorbar(cntr1, ticks=levels)

plt.show()
```

Resulting plot with first 4 levels all the same color (I want them to be different colors):

[image: result]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321390/colormap-is-being-ignored-for-matplotlib-contourf-plot-with-custom-levels  You need a `BoundaryNorm`.

Comment: Good find @JohanC - that was a hard one to find...